# SQL Server query against two linked databases using different collations

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I've got 2 remote databases as part of a query

```
select p.ID,p.ProjectCode_VC,p.Name_VC,v.*
FROM [serverB].Projects.dbo.Projects_T p
LEFT JOIN [serverA].SOCON.dbo.vw_PROJECT v on
p.ProjectCode_VC = v.PROJ_CODE
```

The problem is that serverA uses collation `Latin1_General_BIN` and serverB uses `Latin1_General_CP1_CP_AS` and the query refuses to run.

Both servers are SQL 2000 servers.  Both databases are set in stone so I cannot change their collations, unfortunately.

Is there anyway you guys know how to get this to work?

**Update:**  I found an alternative solution.  In the Linked Server Properties, you can specify the linked server's collation there.

Comment: If both servers have the same collation, you can set collation compatibility on the linked server to "true" to boost performance.

Comment: Small point discovered today: If you force the collation of the linked server, then the query engine may not be able to use remote indexes and will instead need to fetch more data for local comparison/filtering! (eg if you see "Remote Scan" query plan operator, this is a potentially very bad sign)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add the collation to your select, like:

```
select 
  p.ID,
  p.ProjectCode_VC,
  p.Name_VC,
  v.* 
FROM
  [serverB].Projects.dbo.Projects_T p 
  LEFT JOIN [serverA].SOCON.dbo.vw_PROJECT v on p.ProjectCode_VC 
    collate Latin1_General_Bin = v.PROJ_CODE
```

or the other way around. So "convert" one of the collations to the other.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use a more generic query like this:

```
select * from profile, userinfo
where profile.custid collate database_default = userinfo.custid collate database_default
```